# Write dictionary or string to XML

Tags: xml, vb.net, string, dictionary

I am looking to write the contents of a dictionary to XML. I have written the dictionary contents to a string as i have been told it is easier to write from a string to XML instead of from a dictionary. But im not sure if this is correct?

Is there any way to write this to XML from the dictionary or string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a very open-ended question since the format of the desired XML will determine the output.

One very easy way is to roll your own XML:

```
    Dim sbService As New StringBuilder

    sbService.AppendLine("<?xml version=""1.0""?>")
    sbService.AppendLine("<services>")

    For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, Services) In dictservice
        sbService.AppendFormat("  <service DisplayName=""{0}"" ServiceName=""{1}""></service>", item.Key, item.Value.ToString()).AppendLine()
    Next
    sbService.AppendLine("</services>")
```

This will produce XML similar to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<services>
  <service DisplayName="Application Experience" ServiceName="AeLookupSvc"></service>
</services>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it didnt want to be too specific so that i could do most the work myself. If i wanted to write this to an actual xml to be saved to a location on disk would i need to use a text writer of some sort?

Comment: It's even easier than a textwriter: `System.IO.File.WriteAllText("c:\test.xml", sbService.ToString)`

Comment: If i had multiple entries under my value in my dictionary, is there anyway i can put each value in separate tags? I will update my code to help explain myself